# Bug in NET Framework String.Remove(char) method?

Tags: c#, .net, string, overloading

```
("hello").Remove('e');
```

So `String.Remove` has many overloads, one of which is : `String.Remove(int startIndex)`

Somehow the character I've written `'e'` gets converted to an `int` and the WRONG overloaded function is called. This is completely unexpected behivour. Do I just have to live with this or is it possible to possibly file a bug so it gets corrected in the next version of the (holy) .NET framework?

Comment: That's because of the bad design decision of implicit type casting char to int.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - there's no Remove method that takes a char.

Comment: @ChrisF: No, but one that takes `int` and `char` is implicitely castable to `int`. That's why above code compiles but throws a runtimew exception since it's out of range.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I've just double checked and I'm surprised that it does that. Normally everything needs casting in C#

Comment: _.NET fanboys, you can kill me if I'm wrong, and downvote and close this question and everything [...]_ hehe, nice intro. Don't get me wrong, I'm also a _fanboy_, but the intro is unique... :oD

Comment: And it's C# related, not .Net. :)

Comment: There is some reasoning and logic here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/01/why-does-char-convert-implicitly-to-ushort-but-not-vice-versa.aspx

Comment: string.Remove has "many overloads"?  I wouldn't call 2 overloads "many"!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[String.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/143t8z3d.aspx) has precisely **2** overloads, both of which take an `int` as their first parameter.

I believe you are looking for [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx), as in

```
string newString = "hello".Replace("e", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no `Remove` method that takes a `char`...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/143t8z3d.aspx

However, `char` can be implicitly cast to an `int`, so in your case it is. But it won't actually remove the letter `e`, but instead the character at index `(int)'e'` (which will be out of range at runtime in your case).

If you want to "remove" the letter `e`, then:

```
var newString = "Hello".Replace("e", "");
```

I predict there might be a future run-in with the immutability of strings. Good luck ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Please look at the intellisense for the method: it is:

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Returns a new string in which all the characters in the current instance,
    //     beginning at a specified position and continuing through the last position,
    //     have been deleted.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   startIndex:
    //     The zero-based position to begin deleting characters.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     A new string that is equivalent to this string except for the removed characters.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
    //     startIndex is less than zero.-or- startIndex specifies a position that is
    //     not within this string.
    public string Remove(int startIndex);
```

It does what it says; it just isn't the method you want. What you want is:

```
string s = "hello".Replace("e","");
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove takes an integer as its parameter, not a char. 'e' gets turned into 101 as an int.

Answer (score 2):

What is your question?

As there is no overload that takes a `char` as parameter, you can't expect to remove `'e'` this way.

Just use `string.Replace(string, string)`.

Answer (score 1):

string.Remove() only has 2 overloads, one of which accepts an int parameter (and none of which take a char parameter).

Chars are trivially convertable to ints.

Therefore string.Remove(int) is called.

Not a bug. :)